# Unit Tests Run Twice in IntelliJ

Tags: junit, intellij-idea

I'm new to IntelliJ. I have some unit tests written in JUnit. For some reason, each tests runs twice. For the life of me, I can't figure out why. Can someone please provide some pointers in regards to why this might be happening. I would really like to get this down to a predicatable state.

Thanks

Comment: How are you running your tests?  Do you have test-suites defined?

Comment: I'm running the unit tests in IntelliJ via a Run/Debug configuration. I do have my test suites defines.

Answer (score 0):

For example if you have a method annotated both with @Before and @Test annotations it will run twice:

```
@Test
@Before
public void testConnection()
{
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into an apparent (but only apparent) case of this as well. I was logging something at the beginning of the test and then the log message was showing up twice in the console, which made it look like the test was running twice.

The problem was that I had log4j misconfigured. My root logger was like this:

`log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout`

But my package-specific logger was like this:

`log4j.logger.com.mycompany.myapp=TRACE, stdout`

[Log4j additivity](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Additivity) resulted in the double-log.

The fix was simply to update my package-specific logger as follows:

`log4j.logger.com.mycompany.myapp=TRACE`

Hope this helps somebody out. This was aggravating.